# Prolog Count the number of fact in a Table

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I have a program asking patients if they have symptoms like cold, fever, etc.

Based on their answers a fact table is done using the dynamic: and assert command. The fact table at the end looks something like the following.

```
symptom(fever).
symptom(cough).
symptom(coldness).
symptom(tiredness).

....
```

Due are many symptoms and possible combinations of true and false answers. The objective is that if for example in the fact tables are created 3 symptoms the person has a 45% of being sick with 4 symptoms 55% etc.

How can I code something like the one mentioned before?

Any idea? Can you give me a hand?

Comment: You can also use findall/3 and length/2 to be independent to the prolog implementation

Answer (score 2):

To get the number of clauses for `symptom/1`, use [predicate_property/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=predicate_property/2) as follows:

```
?- predicate_property(symptom(_), number_of_clauses(N)).
N = 4.
```

Answer (score -1):

As per example at https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=nb_setarg/3 , with slight style change:

```
succeeds_n_times(Goal, Times) :-
    Count = c(0),
    forall(
        call_nth(Goal, Nth),
        nb_setarg(1, Count, Nth)
    ),
    arg(1, Count, Times).

symptom(fever).
symptom(cough).
symptom(coldness).
symptom(tiredness).

symptom_count(Count) :-
    succeeds_n_times(symptom(_), Count).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- symptom_count(C).
C = 4.
```

Comment: You are using a specific SWI-Prolog extension to do this; but there are better ways to achieve the same in SWI-Prolog. Not a good approach.

Comment: Still interesting and worth mentioning though, yes? I suppose involving `call_nth` would be more elegant.

Comment: Switched to using `call_nth` and `forall`, to be shorter and more elegant.

Comment: Not sure, I would guess that using predicate_property/2 is better in almost every way. But yes this approach is good to understand, too.